# Firebase and react native :Invalid APNs certificate.Check certificate settings

Tags: firebase, push-notification, react-native-ios, react-native-fcm

I used react-native-fcm, no error and no warning but when I tried to send push notif using firebase, I got an error:-

> Invalid APNs certificate. Check certificate settings.

Even though I used **APNs Authentication Key**. Is there anyone solved this issue? Please help me.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you resolve this?